# ¿Como puedo guardar la Uri de una imagen una vez creada en android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, uri

El siguiente método me devuelve un File, pero no logro conseguir establecerlo en un imageView

```
public File SaveImage(Bitmap ImageToSave) {

String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + NameOfFolder;

String CurrentDateAndTime = getCurrentDateAndTime();
File dir = new File(file_path);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
File file = new File(dir, NameOfFile + CurrentDateAndTime + ".jpg");
try {
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
    MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(file);
    AbleToSave();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    UnableToSave();
}
catch(IOException e) {
    UnableToSave();
}

//return file.getPath();
//return file.getAbsolutePath();
return file;
}

File file = saveImage(currentBitmap);

Picasso.get().load(file.getAbsolutePath()).into(imageView);
```

Y no uso el currentBitmap porque es para almacenar una una base de datos.

Comment: Para cargar la imagen con `Picasso` :
`Picasso.with(<<context | activity >>).load(<<Uri | Path | etc>>).error(R.drawable.error).fit().into(imageView);`

Comment: Agrega un ejempo de como llamas SaveImage() para guiarte en como obtener la Uri o donde almacenas lo que obtienes de este método.

Comment: @Jorgesys lo invoco pasandole una BitMap temporal, el cual no puedo utilizar para poner en el imageView ya que estos serán guardados en una base de deatos Realm y ocupa demasiado espacio, por eso solo me sirve el File.

Comment: El valor de SaveImage() es String pero es una Uri por lo tanto solo usa  Uri uriImage = Uri.parse(valorSaveImage); para convertirlo a Uri. @JhonArias

Answer (score 0):

Al salvar la imagen tu método retorna la `Uri` en formato `string`:

```
...
return Uri.fromFile(file).toString();
...
```

por lo tanto para obtener la `Uri` nuevamente puedes usar `Uri.parse()`, pero debes asegurar que el valor del string que se use en realidad sea el obtenido por `SaveImage()`:

```
  Uri uriImage = Uri.parse(valorSaveImage);
```